# Converting Old Dimmer 3 Way Switch to Kasa Wifi Smart Dimmer

Tags: switch, light, smart-switch

So I want to install my Kasa Smart wifi Dimmer. The Kasa switch has 4 connections. A neutral, a ground and two screws one red screw labeled LOAD and one black screw labeled LINE.

My current set up is a 3 way switch with 2 black wires, 1 red wire and a ground. The 1 red wire is connected to a brass screw at the top of the switch. 1 black wire is connected to a brown screw below the red and the other black wire is connected to a brass screw at the bottom of the switch on the opposite side of the switch.

How do I connect this?
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Read the instructions.

Answer (score 2):

You can't get there from here.

The HS220 is a single pole switch. You need the KS230 kit if you want to do this with Kasa. There are other similar devices available from other manufacturers.

The red and black wires that are both on brass screws are the *travelers*. Some smart 3-way switches use both travelers together with an ordinary toggle switch for the second switch. Some use both travelers with two smart switches (KS230). Some use just one traveler. But all will need you to identify the travelers. Follow the directions carefully, as there is no standard of top/bottom/left/right for travelers vs. common wires. On most non-smart switches, the travelers are identified by being the two wires on the same color screw (typically brass vs. black).

Based on the picture, it looks like you have a neutral bundle in this box. That is good as most (but not all) smart switches require neutral. But it gets extra tricky with smart switches. You will need an "always hot", and it is possible to have a switch of a 3-way set that has neutral but does not have "always hot" in the same box.